# First character from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i Have use ajax in my code and i want to get the first character from the response of the object how it is possible?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url : "receiver.html",
    data : "key1=" + key1,
    success : function(message) {
    alert(message.charAt(0));             
    }
});
```

In above code i want the first character of the message is  it possible and if yes then how? and if no then please give alternative of this...

Comment: Whats the content of `receiver.html`

Comment: Have you run the above code? Does it work? If not, what error message does it give?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, if the content of `receiver.html` is some string like `abcd`

Comment: It's a String (name of user)

Comment: [If you consult the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you will see that the `success` method's first parameter is not a string, it is an object. It is difficult to tell what you are expecting it to do since we do not know what response your `receiver.html` is supposed to be sending back.

Comment: Charlie Kilian ---- It's not give any error.

Comment: You need to also add a handler to the `error` function.

Comment: Why don't use `substr()` ? -> `alert(message.substring(0, 1))`

Comment: i also use error fro handling a error ... but when i receive a response..that response contain message ..that message on i can not perform substitution or response.charAt(0) function...i can get whole string instead of one character of string

Comment: try this `message[0]` without any function just use index...

Answer (score 1):

You should check the length of your `message string` like,

```
if(message.length) {
   alert(message.charAt(0));//alert(message.substring(0,1));
} else {
   alert('Empty string');
}
```

Comment: No,it's not work now i have put one answer and it's successful

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning just the String from other page then 
You should use something like::

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST'
    url : "receiver.html",
    data : "key1=" + key1,
    success : function(message) {
    alert(message[0]);             
    }
});
```

FOr your good Reference have a quick look at::
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/8GM4E/

Comment: What is the Format of data you are getting in response after ajax post?
will be helpfull if you will provide me a sample

Comment: also provide the type of AJAX post in your code as I have edited in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

alert(message.substring(0,1));

or

alert(message.slice(0,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer of this thing and it's success we have to convert the response in String

```
$.ajax({
    url : "receiver.html",
    data : "key1=" + key1,
    success : function(message) {
    message=message.toString();
    alert(message.charAt(0));             
    }
});
```

This is give output Succefully